# How to fire mouse click event for a user controls in a table layout panel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, mouseevent, tablelayoutpanel

I got a problem to fire a mouse click event for user controls in a table layout panel. I created a user control with this class.

```
public partial class ComputerControl : UserControl
{
    private int computerId;

    public int ComputerId
    {
        get { return computerId; }
        set { computerId = value; }
    }

    private String computerName;

    public String ComputerName
    {
        get { return computerName; }
        set { computerName = value; }
    }

    private String computerIp;

    public String ComputerIp
    {
        get { return computerIp; }
        set { computerIp = value; }
    }

    private String computerMacAddress;

    public String ComputerMacAddress
    {
        get { return computerMacAddress; }
        set { computerMacAddress = value; }
    }

    private Image computerPicture;

    public Image ComputerPicture
    {
        get { return computerPicture; }
        set { computerPicture = value; }
    }

    private RightClikControl rightClick = new RightClikControl();

    public RightClikControl RightClick
    {
        get { return rightClick; }
        set { rightClick = value; }
    }

    public ComputerControl(int computerId, String computerName, String computerIp, String computerMacAddress, Image computerPicture)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComputerId = computerId;
        ComputerName = computerName;
        ComputerIp = computerIp;
        ComputerMacAddress = computerMacAddress;
        ComputerPicture = computerPicture;
        labelComputerState.Text = ComputerName;
        pictureBoxComputer.Image = ComputerPicture;
    }

    private void ComputerControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            RightClick.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I added more than one controls to table layout panel with this method.

```
private void InsertComputers()
    {
        int i, j;
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.Visible = false;
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.Controls.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.RowStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.ColumnStyles.Clear();
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.ColumnCount = tableLayoutPanelComputers.Size.Width / 130;
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.RowCount = tableLayoutPanelComputers.Size.Height / 100;

        for (i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanelComputers.RowCount; i++)
        {
            tableLayoutPanelComputers.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100));
        }
        for (j = 0; j < tableLayoutPanelComputers.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            tableLayoutPanelComputers.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 130));
        }
        int clientCount = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanelComputers.RowCount && clientConf.Count > clientCount; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < tableLayoutPanelComputers.ColumnCount && clientConf.Count > clientCount; j++)
            {
                ComputerControl cc = new ComputerControl(clientConf[clientCount].ClientId, clientConf[clientCount].ClientName, clientConf[clientCount].ClientIp, clientConf[clientCount].ClientMacAddress,Images.Pc_PowerOff);
                tableLayoutPanelComputers.Controls.Add(cc, j, i);
                clientCount++;
            }
        }
        tableLayoutPanelComputers.Visible = true;
    }
```

So, when I clicked the right mouse button on a user control in a table layout panel cell any thing fire up.

What I'm coding wrong?

Comment: Have you registered `ComputerControl_MouseClick` to a mouse event anywhere? Maybe I glossed over it, but I don't see it. EDIT: Oh, silly me, probably auto-wired from the designer view.

Comment: You can programmatically register the event listener to your new controls when you create them: `cc.MouseDown += ComputerControl_MouseClick;`

Comment: @Chris Sinclair, It didn't work. When I click a user control in tlp cell any thing fire up. When I click an area out of User control mouse down event fire up.

Comment: Dear Friends,
I found my problem. The reason of problem I just set the event for user control but I got picture box label and a table layout panel in that user control. So when I set all components mouse click events every thing will worked fine. Thank you.